# PluginQGIS : how to interact with GUI from function file (import in the main file)

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.14

I am making a QGIS plugin with QGIS 2.14.10.

Then i have a main file : myPlugin.py and a functions file call in the main file : myFunctions.py

In the file myPlugin.py, I can print a message in the GUI using self.dlg.textBrowser.append("Mon message") :

```
...    
import myFunctions
from myFunctions import *

...

    class myPlugin:
        """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

        def __init__(self, iface):
            """Constructor.
            :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
                which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
                application at run time.
            :type iface: QgsInterface
            """
         ...

         def run(self):
             self.dlg.textBrowser.append("Mon message")
             QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

My question is how can I print a message in the GUI from the function file myFunctions.py ?

in the myFunctions.py I tried :

```
import myPlugin
from myPlugin import *

def function_1 (Message) :

   myPlugin.dlg.textBrowser.append(Message)
```

But it doesn't work.